# Could a weapon utilize artificial lightning?

Tags: physics, electricity, lightning

*We all know how lightning works: The clouds have a strong static charge and release that charge towards the ground. But could it be used as a weapon?*

**Would a weapon of the following description work? Would it be practical for mass destruction?**

A strongly positively charged piece of metal is fired at a target. Then, a machine builds up a very strong positive charge. Because of the charge difference, a strong electrical current flows through the air and strikes the target.

Comment: Such a weapon is more likely to strike anything BUT the desired target (lower resistance to strike the wielder, the tree over there, that mailbox, the ground itself...).

Comment: The charged metal is there to prevent that

Comment: A negatively charged shard of metal is both the wrong charge AND deadly on its own.  Its called a "bullet"

Comment: Ok, I'll change the charge.

Comment: How could the weapon harness the power of artificial lightning, would it not create the lightning to begin with?

Comment: If you really want this gun to work, you need to ionize the air so that there's a viable least-resistance path to the target.  Simply injecting a charged plate on the target isn't going to do anything: you're trying to overcome the electrical resistance of the air and "less air" is going to be preferrable over "more air" in nearly ever scenario.

Comment: And bullets have extremely limited destructive power. They are effective against "soft" targets, but against a heavily armor-plated target or against a building they have limited effectiveness.

Comment: Throwing more metal at a metal-covered opponent is going to do diddly squat.  Charged or no.

Comment: Doesn't the lightning bolt ionize the air? If it doesn't, what happens in lightning?

Comment: This question is nearly identical to that of Culyx.